# Error when attempting to call a remote method in DBus

Tags: methods, glib, dbus

I am trying to invoke a remote method using

```
dbus_g_proxy_call(proxy,"myFunc",&error,G_TYPE_INVALID,G_TYPE_INVALID);
```

but when I try this I get an error message saying "Method "myFunc" with signature "" on interface "com.myinterface.dbus" doesn't exist". What am I doing wrong in this? myFunc is of type void and no input parameters to it.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that the server does not have a method with this name/signature combination at the path that your `proxy` is set up to use.

This can happen for a number of reasons, it may have crashed or just not be running for some other reason, or it may not have registered the function correctly.

Alternatively, you may not be using the correct path when creating your `proxy`, or your server may be registering the method at the wrong path.

Without seeing more of your code, it is hard to say what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Introspecting the objects, interfaces and methods actually exported by your service using a tool like [D-Feet](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/DFeet) would probably help here.